# mongodb.countDocuments is slow when result set is large even if index is used

Tags: mongodb

`mongodb.countDocuments` is slow when result set is large

Test data on users collection:

- 10M documents with status `'active'`
- 100k documents with status `'inactive'`

The field `status` is indexed {status: 1}

`db.users.countDocuments({status: 'active'})` takes  2.91 sec
`db.users.countDocuments({status: 'inactive'})` takes 0.018 sec

I understand that `countDocuments` uses an aggegation to find and count the results.

`estimatedDocumentCount`() does not work in this case because  query filter is needed

Any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Counting *seems* like one of those things that should be cheap, but often isn't. Because mongo doesn't maintain a count of the number of documents that match certain criteria in its b-tree index, it needs to scan through the index counting documents as it goes. That means that counting 100x the documents will take 100x the time, and this is roughly what we see here -- `0.018 * 100 = 1.8s`.

To speed this up, you have a few options:

1. The active count is roughly `estimatedDocumentCount() - db.users.countDocuments({status: 'inactive'})`. Would this be accurate enough for your use case?
2. Alternatively, you can maintain a `counts` document in a separate collection that you keep in sync with the number of active/inactive documents that you have.

Comment: thanks willis
option 1 is a great options but it'll have a problem if i don't knows which status has lower documents
option 2 is what i do now, just need to confirm that no better ways to do this so i'll keep it as by mongodb count best practice