# C# MongoDB Driver ToList() paginated query, with having indexes to slow on large data around 50M

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using the latest MongoDB C# driver version 2.10 in my dotnet core app. I have 50+ million records. All columns indexed properly and queries are working fine on Compass.

Here is the method I have.

```
 /// <summary>
 /// fetch all items in collection with paging and ordering in direction
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="pageIndex">page index, based on 0</param>
 /// <param name="size">number of items in page</param>
 /// <param name="order">ordering parameters</param>
 /// <param name="fields">required fields</param>
 /// <param name="filters">search criteria</param>
 /// <returns>collection of entity</returns>

 Task<(IEnumerable<T> result, long count)> FindAllListAsync(int? pageIndex, int? size, string order = null, string fields = null, string filters = null);
```

**Here is the implementation**

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindAll(int? pageIndex, int? size, out long count, string order = null, string fields = null, string filters = null)
    {
        IFindFluent<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument, MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument> fluent;
        long totalCount;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filters))
        {
            fluent = CollectionAsBson.Find(filters);
            totalCount = fluent.CountDocuments();
        }
        else
        {
            fluent = CollectionAsBson.Find(FilterDefinition<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>.Empty);
            totalCount = Collection.EstimatedDocumentCount();
        }
        if (pageIndex.HasValue && size.HasValue)
            fluent = fluent.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * size);

        if (size.HasValue)
            fluent = fluent.Limit(size);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(order))
        {
            fluent = fluent.Sort(order);
        }

        fluent.Options.Collation = new Collation("en");
        IEnumerable<T> result = fluent.Project<T>(fields).ToList();

        count = totalCount;
        return result;
    }
```

**I called in this way**

```
public async Task<(IEnumerable<T> result, long count)> FindAllListAsync(int? pageIndex, int? size, string order = null, string fields = null, string filters = null)
   {
       long localCount = 0;
       var list = await Task.Run(() => FindAll(pageIndex, size, out localCount, order, fields, filters)).ConfigureAwait(true);
       return (list, localCount);
   }
```

This code taking too much time to get even 5 records with paging.  When I return `fluent.Project<T>(fields).ToEnumerable()` it returns with async cursor which is not evaluated. But when I put mapping code such as `AutoMapper` or even do `toList()` after that it takes too much time. Even `countDocuments` takes too much time.

Here are my indexes.

[image]

Comment: does the query become fast if you comment out counting? also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57801753/mongodb-countdocuments-is-slow-when-result-set-is-large-even-if-index-is-used)

Comment: My first issue was with toList()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AsQueryable()`. This will transform the data you want into a query.

Comment: `var mapped = await data.result.AsQueryable().ProjectTo<CompanyLeads>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync();`
I tried this also when I set IEnumerable in find. This also stucks