# In C#, how can I timebox a counting operation?

Tags: c#, mongodb, time, limit, counting

We have a method which, among other things, returns a count of documents in a MongoDb collection.  [When there is a lot of data and not many filters, this can take an insanely long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57801753/mongodb-countdocuments-is-slow-when-result-set-is-large-even-if-index-is-used).

Well, it turns out, *most* of the time we don't actually need this value, or when we do it can be returned in a reasonable amount of time (because either the collection has less records, the request has more filters, or we have been able to anticipate the need and apply suitable filters.

I would like to somehow wrap `await collection.CountDocumentsAsync(filters, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);` in some sort of function which would limit counting to half a second.

If it gets a result, return it.
It not, return `Int32.MaxValue` instead.

Is this possible?
If so, how?

Comment: Use a `CancellationToken` that cancels after a given time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a cancellation token with a time limit. Create a new token using a [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-threading-cancellationtokensource-ctor(system-timespan)) that lets you specify the maximum duration. For example:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

var documentCount = int.MaxValue;

try
{
    documentCount = await collection.CountDocumentsAsync(filters,
        cancellationToken: cts.Token);
}
catch(TaskCanceledException)
{
    // Or ignore this if you don't care
    Console.WriteLine("Task lasted longer than 30 seconds");    
}

// Now documentCount will be equal to int.MaxValue 
// if the operation takes longer than 30 seconds
```

Comment: Looks good!  Any advantage to assigning `int.MaxValue` when declaring `documentCount` over setting it in the `catch block?

Comment: No, you could return it directly from inside the `catch`, entirely up to you.